# Is the Oval ( based on Ptolemy inequality) known?

Tags: algebraic-curves

It has a property of enclosing quadrilaterals so the ratio of their diagonals product  and sum of their opposite sides pair  products is constant $(e<1)$. The curve is from a family defined by the [Ptolemy Inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAkCG.png)

In order to rope in the Ptolemy Inequality Oval took three points on a unit generating circle radius $ a=1 $ and the fourth one outside the circle

$$(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(x,y)$$

as particular vertices of a non-cyclic  quadrilateral. The ratio $e$ defines its equation.

$$ \dfrac{\sqrt 2 \sqrt{x^2+(1+y)^2}}{\sqrt{y^2+(x+1)^2} + \sqrt{y^2+(x-1)^2}} =e<1 \tag 1 $$

Special case  $e=1$ is the circle enclosing cyclic quadrilaterals that have the property given by Ptolemy theorem. A set of non-cyclic quadrilaterals can be inscribed in this oval shape. In this drawing $ e=0.95; $

[image]

Some shapes for [Other $e$ values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3889072/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-this-vector-equality-vecbc-cdot-vecad-v/3891833#3891833)

Further simplification yields a fourth degree algebraic curve:

$$\left(-a^4-2 a^3 y+a^2 \left(2 \left(e^2-1\right) x^2-2 y^2\right)-2 a y \left(x^2+y^2\right)-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2\right)+\frac{\left((a+y)^2+x^2\right)^2}{2 e^2}=0$$

Comment: What's the oval's equation?

Comment: Given derivation of a particular case.

Comment: BTW: "oval" isn't quite a suitable name for that curve since it's not egg-shaped ...

Comment: More profiles/closed contours  are added. Any other name suggestions?

Comment: The images posted so far remind me on a painter's palette, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_(painting)

Comment: Did you see under "other e values"? There is a circle, a pear like shape and the painter's pallette.

Comment: Hmm... if you take a circle inversion wrt $(0,-1)$, the oval get mapped to  an ellipse. so the oval is an [inverse curve](Inverse curve) of ellipse. Unfortunately, the wiki entry doesn't have enough info whether this curve has been seriously studied before.

Comment: maybe Cardoids? trying to find the generation of these curves.  Are these ovals inversions to some ellipses ? Like the red colored egg sketched? what could be the centers, axes and shifts of the ellipses?

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment because I want to insert a picture [image]

You can find it here https://mathcurve.com/courbes3d/crepe/crepe.shtml . Sorry if the link is in french .

Hope it helps you !

Comment: Can you please say which are the equations of surfaces intersecting  to result in  these  2d ovals ?

Comment: @Narasimham    See here https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/oeuf/oeufgranville.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Not another answer. For comments/ achille hui with sketch:

```
h = 1.4; a = .5; b = 0.3; A = 1;
mirror = ParametricPlot[{A Cos[t], A Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
ell = ParametricPlot[{h + a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}];
Oval = ParametricPlot[
   A^2 {h + a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}/((h + a Cos[t])^2 + (b Sin[t])^2), {t,
     0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Show[{ell, Oval, mirror}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]